# What type of function can I apply to both sides of an inequality in order to obtain an equivalent inequality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, inequality

I'd like to know what are the types of functions that I can apply to both sides of an inequality in order to get an equivalent inequality. *Are those functions the ones that are strictly increasing or strictly decreasing?* I'm not sure about it.
Also, I'd like to get a recommendation about good sources where I can read about it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by "equivalent inequality" you mean $a<b \iff f(a)<f(b)$ then $f$ must be strictly increasing - for example:

$a<b \iff a+k < b+k\\
a<b \iff ka < kb, \space k>0\\
a<b \iff a^3 < b^3\\
a<b \iff \root{3}\of{a} < \root{3}\of b\\
a<b \iff \tan(a) < \tan(b), \space -\frac \pi 2 <a,b<\frac \pi 2$

If $f$ is strictly decreasing then the inequality is reversed i.e. the equivalence becomes $a<b \iff f(a) > f(b)$. For example:

$a<b \iff ka > kb, \space k<0\\
a<b \iff \frac 1 a > \frac 1 b, \space a,b>0$

Answer (score -1):

It is always true that $a=b$ implies $f(a)=f(b)$, no matter what function $f$ is.
But in order to justify that $f(a)=f(b)$ implies $a=b$ (or, taken together, that $a=b$ is equivalent to $f(a)=f(b)$), you better consider only *injective* functions $f$.

Indeed, $f(a)=f(b)\implies a=b$ for all applicable $a,b$ is precisely the definition of $f$ being injective. Of course, strictly increasing (or decreasing) functions are in particular injective.

Comment: The OP's question is about inequalities. Not equalities. If you edit your question to address this I will remove the downvote.